# How do I perform joins with lithium models?

Tags: lithium

I read through lithium\data\model\query, but I didn't see any examples of joins.

Comment: did you look at the test cases? maybe there are some...

Comment: @Tomen When I wrote the question, no, thanks for the suggestion. I just checked it out, but I'm not really sure what the test is doing? What are foo, bar, and baz supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to perform a join with Lithium.

1. Lithium will handle joins for you where you have defined relationships ([examples in the manual](http://li3.me/docs/book/manual/1.x/models/relationships)).
2. You can add joins to an existing Query object using the `join()` method (see the <strike>API</strike>)).
3. You can pass an array of Query objects to finders using the key `joins`.
4. You can pass the SQL directly to a connection using `Connection->read()`.

The other methods are reasonably well documented, so I'll give an example of passing Query objects to a finder.

```php
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'slug');                                                                                                                                                                                                  
$joins = array();
$joins[] = new Query(array(
  'source' => 'client_tests',  
  'constraint' => array('Test.id' => 'client_tests.test_id'),
));
$conditions['client_id'] = $this->data['client_id'];
$tests = Test::all(array(
   'conditions' => $conditions,
   'fields' => $fields,
   'joins' => $joins
));
```

The `source` is the table that you want to join and `constraint` is the join criteria. Lithium aliases the find table to the name of the model, so use that in your constraint. You can then pass the joins in to any finder along with any other parameters you want.

Note that at the time of writing, joins (and relationships) will only work with a relational database, not for things like MongoDB's DBRef.

**Update**: Removed links that have been link jacked.

Comment: Hi, sorry to necro this, my query is failing on the field names. For example, if slug was in both tables, one with a capital S, one with a lowercase s, the lowercase s can get specified through table.slug, but the uppercase S only shows table2. IE: "SELECT table.slug, table" instead of "SELECT table.slug, table2.slug". I'm guess this has to do with human translation function stuff lithium has?

Comment: This sounds like a lithium bug. Check the lithium github issues, and if it doesn't exist yet, open an issue and attach a failing test case.

Comment: Your API link in item #2 has been link jacked by some SEO company (EDIT: Both links actually).

Comment: Thanks mopsyd, I've removed the links and become marginally sadder at the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a relationship (using hasOne, hasMany, or belongsTo) you can fetch the related data by supplying a `with` key in the options of your `find` call.

Like this:

```php
$categories = Categories::find('all', array(
  'with' => 'Products'
));
```

Check out the [manual chapter on Relationships](http://li3.me/docs/book/manual/1.x/models/relationships) for more detail.

Comment: While it's true that relationships will manage joins for you, it's wrong to say that arbitrary joins aren't possible.

Comment: Cool, I removed that from my answer.