# How to code tag cloud in Ltihium without HABTM?

Tags: has-and-belongs-to-many, lithium

I'm a little foggy with Lithiums relationships. I'm trying to create a tag cloud using Lithium but I'm not sure how to do this without using HABTM relationships.
I'm using MySQL, btw.

Any suggestions?

:edited to add sample code:

Here is a very simplified version of something I'm working on right now.
I have `Items`, `Tags` and `ItemsTags`.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class Tags extends \app\extensions\data\Model {

    public $hasMany   = array('ItemsTags');

    // {{{ schema
    protected $_schema = array(
        'id'       => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'title'    => array('type' => 'string'),
        'created'  => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'integer')
    );
    // }}}
}

?>



<?php

namespace app\models;

class Items extends \app\extensions\data\Model {

    public $hasMany   = array('ItemsTags');

    // {{{ schema
    protected $_schema = array(
        'id'          => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'title'       => array('type' => 'string'),
        'sku'         => array('type' => 'string'),
        'price'       => array('type' => 'float'),
        'created'     => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'modified'    => array('type' => 'integer')
    );
    // }}}
}

?>



<?php

namespace app\models;

class ItemsTags extends \app\extensions\data\Model {

    public $belongsTo = array('Tags', 'Items');

    // {{{ schema
    protected $_schema = array(
        'id'       => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'tag_id'   => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'item_id'  => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'created'  => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'integer')
    );
    // }}}
}
?>



<?php
    $items = Items::find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('myField' => 'myCondition')
    ));
?>
```

How can I change my code so that I can access `Tags` data via `$items`

Comment: could you please give an example? =) i would like to help but can not understand the problem

Comment: Thanks Tomen. I've edited my original post to show my models.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: im sorry i dont know the answer to this. i suggest you try asking via IRC

Answer (score 1):

If you using SQL take a look into: [How do I perform joins with lithium models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391062/how-do-i-perform-joins-with-lithium-models)
for join examples.

Another way might be designing a "Join"Model which is using an own habtm query. There are some cakePHP Examples out there which should be adaptable with not much hazzle.

Or, using noSQL with embedded Documents.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I'm using SQL. I should have mentioned that. I'll edit the original post.
I know how to use find() and invoke joins. I'm just not sure how to implement HABTM within models. For example, I wouldn't know how to use hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, etc in order to simulate HABTM.

I'll Google and look for the way Cake does it. That might help a bit.

Comment: You could create three models => two "normal" ones and one n to m "Model": Users, UsersToCities, Cities.

then relate them as usual.

Comment: But how would I get the Cities data while iterating through the Users?