# Lithium with left join

Tags: sql, lithium

I'm new with `Lithium`.I need to do a left join.This is the `query` I need.

```
SELECT `title`,`body`,`user_id`,`users`.`username`,`users`.`id` 
FROM `posts` LEFT JOIN `users` 
        ON `user_id` = `users`.`id`
```

I try to do something like this.

```
  $conditions['user_id'] = $this->data['user_id'];
                $posts = Post::all(array(
                  'conditions' => $conditions,
                  'fields' => array('title','body','username'),
                  'join' => array('source' => 'posts', 
                  'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'constraint' => array('post.user_id' => 'Users.id')), 
                     ))->data();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial (using a blog as an example) [here](http://nitschinger.at/Introducing-Relationships-in-Lithium) which explains using **Relationships** in Lithium, Relationships make using relational data and `JOINS` simpler.

You can also [check out](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/relationships.wiki) the official docs as well as this answer: [How do I perform joins with lithium models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391062/how-do-i-perform-joins-with-lithium-models)

Once you have your **Relationships** set on your **Models** you can do your `JOINS` as simply as:

```
$posts = Posts::find('all', array(
    'with' => 'Users'
));
```

There are a couple differant types of Relationships in Lithium, which roughly corrspond to differant types of `JOINS` ...

- **hasOne**: the current object is linked to a single object of another type
- **hasMany**: the current object is linked to many objects of another type
- **belongsTo**: the current object is owned and marked as related to
  another object